# Displaying all the columns of a dataframe after aggregating on one column in a groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of games played by different number of players for each game. Simplified, it looks like this:

```
GameID Player Score
------ ------ -----
1      John   10
1      Alice  20
1      Bob    30
2      John   15
2      Alice  25
```

I'm trying to display the dataframe of the winner of each game but I'm having trouble with the syntax after using `groupby`. I managed to get a Series or a Dataframe of the rows with the highest score in each game by doing either of these:

```
df.groupby('GameID')['Score'].max()
df.groupby('GameID').aggregate({'Score': max})
```

But I'd like to display the entire dataframe, including the `Player` column (as well as other columns present in the dataframe, which I've simplified here).

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: The title could be clearer. At first I thought it was going to be a duplicate of [How to print a groupby object](/q/22691010/4518341), but really you're asking something more like, "How do I get all the columns of a dataframe after aggregating on one column in a groupby?" For more info, [ask] has tips on how to write a good title.

Comment: Related: [Keep other columns when using sum() with groupby](/q/49783178/4518341)

Comment: Thanks. I've modified the title but I can't understand from the linked question how I should proceed. I need to display the single row in the `groupby` object which has the highest value of 'Score' in that group.

Comment: The top answer was kinda unclear, so I edited it. Using that technique, you'd do `idx = df.groupby('GameID')['Score'].transform(max) == df['Score']` then `df[idx]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll look into the `transform` method to see why this works.